# Bi-directional LSTM for variable-length sequence in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, bidirectional

I want to train a bi-directional LSTM in tensorflow to perform a sequence classification problem (sentiment classification).

Because sequences are of variable lengths, batches are normally padded with vectors of zero. Normally, I use the sequence_length parameter in the uni-directional RNN to avoid training on the padding vectors.

How can this be managed with bi-directional LSTM. Does the "sequence_length" parameter work automatically starts from an advanced position in the sequence for the backward direction?

Thank you

Comment: People who cast close votes as too broad: please explain.

Answer (score 2):

`bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` also has a `sequence_length` parameter that takes care of sequences of variable lengths.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bidirectional_dynamic_rnn  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170321202336/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bidirectional_dynamic_rnn)):

> `sequence_length`: An int32/int64 vector, size [batch_size], containing the actual lengths for each of the sequences.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER/blob/master/src/entity_lstm.py

Comment: Thanks @FranckDernoncourt. How about the padding? Do you have to pad at the end for the forward RNN and pad at the beginning at the backward RNN?

Comment: Both of your links are broken.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs SE should take care of archiving links. Anyway please try way back machine.

Answer (score 1):

In forward pass, rnn cell will stop at `sequence_length` which is the no-padding length of the input and is a parameter in `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`. In backward pass, it firstly use function `tf.reverse_sequence` to reverse the first `sequence_length` elements and then traverse like that in the forward pass.

https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/reverse_sequence

> This op first slices input along the dimension `batch_axis`, and for each slice `i`, reverses the first `seq_lengths[i]` elements along the dimension `seq_axis`.